# How to download file given url in java?

Tags: java, file, http, url, download

I want to use file downloaded by this link in java ...

http://translate.google.com/translate_a/…

If you click on above link you will get a file in json format. I want to get this file using java code.

I tried this one

```
String word = "Moon";

System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "172.20.0.100");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");

URL url = new URL("http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&text="+word+"&hl=en&sl=en&tl=hi&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&multires=1&otf=1&ssel=3&tsel=3&sc=1");
url.openConnection();
InputStream reader = url.openStream();
FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream("t");
byte[] buffer = new byte[153600];
int bytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = reader.read(buffer)) > 0)
{  
    writer.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    buffer = new byte[153600];
}
writer.close();
reader.close();
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code:  403 for URL: http://translate.google.com/translate_a/…
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnect…
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1031)
at smsMain.main(smsMain.java:19)
```

Direct download is working ( just click and see translation of word "Moon" in hindi ) but through program it is showing error !!!! why ???

Please help in this regard .
Thank you in advance !!!

Answer (score 4):

You are getting a 403 because Google doesn't want you to use the service in this way: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

If you look at the content of the page, it says: `That’s an error. Your client does not have permission to get URL / from this server.`

To get programatic access to the Google Translate API, you will need to pay for access https://developers.google.com/translate/

Comment: The OP wants to know _why_ it is accessible from the browser but not from the Java application.

Comment: Because you have to [pay for access](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/pricing) to the Translate API

Comment: But if you click on it .. it is getting downloaded though it is a paid service !!! how ???

Comment: The magic of the Internet. There are Google engineers who make the service free through browsers and paid for use programmatically, and ensure that that is the way it is accessed. You might be able to figure out a way around it, but technically you are breaking the law.

Comment: I found url from here  </br> http://rupeshpatel.wordpress.com/2012/06/23/usage-of-google-translator-api-for-free/  </br> have not checked if working or not...

Comment: Note that it says "hacked" at the beginning of the article and that in the comments below several people talk about Google blocking their IP address. It's really not that expensive to just pay for it if you need the functionality.